# How to organize F# and C# side by side

Tags: c#, f#

The project I am working on will have to be migrated from C# to F# based on what brings food on the table tomorrow - in other words, the two languages have to live side by side in this project for years to come.

**The problem I am faced with repeatedly is how I should organize projects in the solution to meet this need.**

I translate pieces from C# to F# all the time, because it frequently shortens the development time and increases the quality. But I end up with C# code that wants to use F# code, and F# code that want to use C# code, in the same layer, or at boundaries between layers or modules. I find myself putting code in the wrong projects just to avoid creating yet another project in some layer.

The situation is not bad now, but I worry that I will paint myself into a corner at some point, unless I can come up with a pattern or a structure, or simply understand the problem better.

**Is there some modification to a normal F# architecture - a pattern, a substructure or a superstructure - that is well suited to such a mixed solution?**

**Are there patterns that are known to be especially helpful in solving this particular challenge?**

Comment: Can you provide an example? I think right now the question has a good topic, but it's a bit too abstract for specific advice.

Comment: One example: I move utility methods from various places into library CsUtils. Then I translate some utility methods to F# and move them into library FsUtils. So far so good. But I want utility methods to be able to use each other. CsUtils can use FsUtils, or FsUtils can use CsUtils, but not both. Do I create yet another library, and will that really be sufficient to solve all the dependency problems that can arise?

Comment: So right now you only have CsUtils, but you're migrating some of them to FsUtils. So CsUtils will need to call some of your FsUtils. But the other way around shouldn't be necessary if you start migrating from those CsUtils that don't depend on other CsUtils.

Comment: But I don't want to depend on translating in that order. I want to translate any piece in a long chain of dependencies.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with concrete dependencies.  If you are applying SOLID/dependency injection etc in your C# code base, it should be straightforward to replace implementations just by implementing interfaces in F# code.  You can keep most of the logic functional and then translate it in C# consumable form at the API boundary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an interface  to communicate between the two languages.

Typically when porting, f# is the lower-level dll and C# can call f# as usual.

Now for f# to call c# define  an interface in the f# dll (e.g. IClibApi) that is implemented in  c# (e.g. ConcreteClibApi extends IClibApi). Create an instance of  ConcreteClibApi and pass it to  f#. Now f# can call  c# thru IClibApi.

Later you can start porting ConcreteClibApi :)